# Will Travel be included in the next "Creative Commons Data Dump"? (And when can we expect it?)

Tags: support, data-dump

Most of us might be unaware that Stack Exchange does public releases from time to time of the data on its Q&A network sites for all interested parties to analyse and play with.

<sup>- [Stack Overflow Creative Commons Data Dump](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/)

- [Meta Stack Overflow `data-dumps` tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-dump)

- [Previous Stack Exchange network data dumps on `clearbits.net`](http://www.clearbits.net/torrents/2076-aug-2012)</sup>

Since I've been analysing and playing with [Wiktionary data dump files](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/latest/) for years, and have also started with [Wikivoyage data dumps](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwikivoyage/latest/) now that it's moved to [WikiMedia](http://www.wikimedia.org/), I am very keen to see what I can extract/analyse/mashup from travel.stackexchange too.

I guess now that we've graduated we should automatically be in the next round of dumps.

But if it's not entirely automated, I'd like to remind our SE overlords not to forget to include us!

But one concern is that the last round of dumps was due out a couple of months ago and still hasn't surfaced ...

**Is the next set of Stack Exchange data dumps coming soon - and will Travel be included?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Travel SE will be included.

I don't have an ETA for the next full data dump, although we are currently hoping to have another one out in the next month or two.

In the meantime, Travel is already up on the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) and eagerly awaiting your queries.

Comment: Yep a bunch of us found and had some fun on the Data Explorer a week or two ago thanks! (-: